# Is it possible to define a string formatter for this method?

Tags: c#, string, console, format, formatter

```
    public string LookAtln(Player p, string thingId, string containerId)
    {
        //I'm not sure using a formatter is good or not
        string f = String.Format ("Look at thingId in containerId");
        ......
    }
```

A user will input like like:

- look at pen in bag
- look at bag in inventory
- look at pen
- look at bag

pen is a item, bag are both item and container, inventory is container. And the method will return a string to describe them.

I'm a new learner on C#, I even cannot sure it is correct to use formatter here or not, if someone have good ideas about this method, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In C# 6 and later you can use it with string interpolation:

```
string f = $"Look at {thingId} in {containerId}";
```

Or if you are targeting an older version,

```
string f = String.Format ("Look at {0} in {1}", thingId, containerId);
```